# Maximum Likelihood Estimation with Mixed Variables

Tags: probability, statistics

I have always wondered about this question, but have never been able to find a satisfactory answer. In the context of statistical regression modelling, estimating the beta regression coefficients of a regression model are often done using Maximum Likelihood Estimation. In many applications involving sociological/economic data, it is common to find that some of the variables are continuous and defined over the "(Positive) Real Domain" (e.g. Continuous Variables: Salary, Weight, Income, etc.) - whereas some of the variables are defined over the "Integer Domain" (e.g. Categorical Variables: Gender, Education Level, Number of Children, etc.). For example, someone can earn a salary of $53,231.02  (continuous number) but can not have 4.21 kids (number of children is an Integer Number).

I have seen again and again that a joint likelihood function is defined using these "mixed variables" (Continuous and Categorical - Positive Reals and Integers) and this joint likelihood function is then optimized for parameter estimation (i.e. estimating the beta coefficients). In practice, this seems to work fine - many times, regression models that are made by optimizing a joint likelihood function composed of mixed random variable types tend to work quite well. It seems like we tend to "assume" that these categorical variables are in fact defined over the Positive Real Domain and carry on with the optimization.  In Machine Learning applications, this is often referred to "One Hot Encoding".

On the other hand, I know that a joint likelihood function can be easily defined for random variables that are only continuous (e.g. Normal Distribution) , and for random variables that are only categorical (e.g. Binomial Distribution).

My question concerns the following point: From a strict mathematical point-of-view - are there are major assumption violations (e.g. axioms of probability) that occur when defining a joint likelihood function over a mixed continuous/categorical domain? Or am I just overthinking this and its perfectly normal and mathematically valid to have a joint likelihood function composed of categorical and continuous random variables?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Remember that a likelihood is neither a probability nor a probability density, and does not have to sum or integrate to $1$ over the possible values of the parameters.  So you can mix the types of variables, and even have variables of mixed type.

Comment: Check https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/248476/119261.